# Can't find links to stargazers anymore

Tags: github

It looks like github has refactored their website. When I click on the "Starred" symbol, it just won't jump, instead it toggles the star on the repo.

[image]

How can I go to the stargazers page?

Answer (score 0):

Those are still available when adding `/stargazers` at the end of the repository URL.

For instance: https://github.com/git/git/stargazers

The link is now at the right side of the repository:

[image: stargazers]